Netsuite restful API full blanket order example
Is there an example out there using the netsuite restful API for using blanket PO.  But "full", I mean:

Create blanket PO, with example end point and JSON
Retrieve BPO
Retrieve schedules of BPO
Create PO against blanket PO, with example end point and JSON.  This probably involves creating a manual schedule and releasing the schedule, but my goal is the discrete PO, however we get there.
Receive against PO or blanket PO.  I guess we receive against PO, but not sure

My problem is that the documentation I have found online seems outdated.  For instance, so far I cannot download the schedule using GET /record/v1/blanketPurchaseOrder/{BPO_ID}/schedule.  It gives an error that "schedule" cannot be found and is an invalid field.  But when I download the full BPO, with subresources expanded, I can see the schedule just fine.  Since I cannot find a complete list of endpoints, I am not even sure if GET is permitted here.
I have not tried the SOAP method yet.
Update:
I submitted the below payload using PUT and POST, but it did not work:
{
    "start_date": "2024-12-11",
    "quantity": 500,
    "item_id": "1031",
    "memo": "Tonyb Test"
}

Here are the HTTP commands I did:
POST /record/v1/blanketPurchaseOrder/{BPOID}/schedule
PUT  /record/v1/blanketPurchaseOrder/{BPOID}/schedule
In both cases, I get the below error:
{
  "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.6",
  "title": "Method Not Allowed",
  "status": 405,
  "o:errorDetails": [
    {
      "detail": "Unsupported HTTP method for the requested resource.",
      "o:errorCode": "INVALID_METHOD"
    }
  ]
}

It is these types of errors that will explain why I would love to see an example of the full process, and I figure if I see an example for steps 1-5 above, it will help me understand better.  I am sure in the above example that either I am not allowed to do what I am doing, or my payload is wrong.  More complete examples would help me figure it out.
BTW, I got the POST and PUT commands using the AI output from one of the search engines.  I never could find where the AI got the commands.
